# Inverse array indexing in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-indexing

I have an array and index list in numpy:

```
ar = np.array([4, 5, 3, -1, -1, 0, 1, 2])
indices = np.array([5, 6, 1, 2, 0, 7, 3, 4])

ar_permuted = ar[indices]
#ar_permuted = array([0, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2, -1, -1])
```

Now, given ar_permuted and indices, what is the most straightforward way to recover ar?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all indices are present.

Using [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
out = ar_permuted[np.argsort(indices)]
```

Using indexing:

```
out = np.zeros(shape=len(ar_permuted), dtype=ar_permuted.dtype)
out[indices] = ar_permuted
```

Output:

```
array([ 4,  5,  3, -1, -1,  0,  1,  2])
```